# How to get specific string in NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa, macos, nspredicate

How to get the string `"NSMetadataItemFSNameKey == *"` in a `NSPredicate`? `predicateWithFormat` doesn't work and crashes.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "NSMetadataItemFSNameKey = *"'
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you post the code where you create the predicate? What are you trying to match against? You want this NSMetadataItemFSKey to be able to be anything? If that is the case, why have the predicate at all?

Comment: This predicate comes from the Apple docs: [click](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH12-SW50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the string `@"NSMetadataItemFSNameKey == *"` and want to turn it into a predicate, you can't.  It's malformed, hence the exception you're getting.

It would need to be:  `@"NSMetadataItemFSNameKey == '*'"`.  Those single quotes around the asterisk are incredibly important.